# PHP Array output shows only in horizontal

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I'm new to PHP and I tried to print array values vertically but it shows values horizontally. This is the code that I tried. Please help me, guys.

```
$roomCount = count($_POST["room_nos"]);
    for($i=0;$i<$roomCount;$i++) {
        foreach($roomsCount as $value){
        
}
        $output.= $roomsCount[$i];
}

echo $output;
```

Current output is 120122.

But I want it as

```
120
122
```

Really waiting for your help.

Comment: You can use \n to break line. `$output.= $roomsCount[$i] . " \n"; `

Comment: @NícolasSimsBotelho has you on the right tack, though it might be better to use `$output.= $roomsCount[$i] . PHP_EOL;`, or,  if you're looking to output this in a browser, you might want `$output.= $roomsCount[$i] . '<br>';` What you use might depend on context, but the main point is that you need to tell your program to output each value on a new line.

Comment: I agree with you @WesleySmith, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I want to display it on the browser. This works. $output.= $roomsCount[$i] . '<br>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use \n to break line. $output.= $roomsCount[$i] . " \n";  Or as @WesleySmith said:
`it might be better to use $output.= $roomsCount[$i] . PHP_EOL;, or, if you're looking to output this in a browser, you might want $output.= $roomsCount[$i] . '<br>';`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add break line to your code.
there is some ways which i know and you have to use them on where needed for example using `<br>` is ok for html but might not gonna work if you are not using php in html codes.

For using in html try this edited code :

```
$roomCount = count($_POST["room_nos"]);
    for($i=0;$i<$roomCount;$i++) {
        foreach($roomsCount as $value){
        
}
        $output.= $roomsCount[$i]."<br>";
        // edited over here // ."<br>" added to your code
}

echo $output;
```

For using in JavaScript or jQuery string returns or console.log or other things you can use this code too :

```
$roomCount = count($_POST["room_nos"]);
    for($i=0;$i<$roomCount;$i++) {
        foreach($roomsCount as $value){

}
        $output.= $roomsCount[$i]."\n";
        // edited over here // ."\n" added to your code
}

echo $output;
```

Also if you are trying to save it on database or using on any API you might need to use this code `PHP_EOL` like this :

```
$roomCount = count($_POST["room_nos"]);
    for($i=0;$i<$roomCount;$i++) {
        foreach($roomsCount as $value){

}
        $output.= $roomsCount[$i].PHP_EOL;
        // edited over here // .PHP_EOL added to your code
}

echo $output;
```

I not sure its all things which you can use but its all codes which i knew i hope its resolve your problem.

Comment: One further option, for what its worth, return JSON string containing just the array of numbers, then, let the front end decide how to display it.

Comment: Great. Really thank you for all of your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

insert a line break :

```
    $output.= sprintf ("%d<br>",$roomsCount[$i]);
```

Comment: only if being outputted into html though. If for example this is outputted into a `textarea` tag, this would fail.

Comment: also, useing `sprintf` here seems a bit like overkill when concatenation would be simpler

Comment: yes. replace the "<br>" by "\n" for the textarea

Answer (score -1):

you can also append `<pre></pre>` html tag to print horizontally in php.

```
 $output .=  '<pre>' . $output .'</pre>';
```